# Bootstrap Modal and legend tag

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

Hi Everyone I am having an issue where I have a Modal window that has two legend tags. The Line under the Legend tag goes outside the modal window.

When I use the same code outside of a modal window it looks fine. I am sure it is something simple that I just cannot see at this point.

This is just a test so the html is quite ugly..

I have created this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jxmccall/3kegahgw/2/)! to demonstrate the issue

Here is the relevant code

```
<div class="container">
<!-- Email Row -->
<div class="form-group">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Login Information</legend>      
    <div class="row">
        <form class="form-inline" role="form">      
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail1" placeholder="Primary Email">
                </div>              
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail1" placeholder="Secondary Email">
                </div>              
            </div>

        </form>

    </div> <!-- End Row -->
        </fieldset>
    </div> <!-- End Form-Group. This adds the space between the rows -->

<!-- Primary Phone -->
<div class="form-group">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Phone Details</legend>
    <div class="row">
  <form role="form" class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
            <input class="form-control" id="primary_phone" name="primary_phone"  type="text" data-mask="(999) 999-9999" placeholder="Primary Phone" />
        </div>      
    </div>
   <div class="form-group">
            <label for="selectUser">Carrier </label>
            <select id="selectUser" class="form-control selectWidth">
              <option class="">AT&T</option>
              <option class="">Verizon</option>
              <option class="">T-Mobile</option>
              <option class="">Sprint</option>
            </select>
    </div>
        <div class="form-group">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <label for="selectUser">Arrival Notifications </label>
            <select id="selectUser" class="form-control selectWidth">
               <option class="">All Arrivals</option>
              <option class="">None</option>
              <option class="">Vendors Only</option>
            </select>
          </div>    


      </form>
    </div> <!-- End Row -->
    </div> <!-- End Form-Group. This adds the space between the rows -->
<!-- Secondary Phone -->
    <div class="row">
  <form role="form" class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
            <input class="form-control" id="primary_phone" name="primary_phone" type="text" data-mask="(999) 999-9999" placeholder="Secondary Phone" />
        </div>      
    </div>
   <div class="form-group">
            <label for="selectUser">Carrier </label>
            <select id="selectUser" class="form-control selectWidth">
              <option class="">AT&T</option>
              <option class="">Verizon</option>
              <option class="">T-Mobile</option>
              <option class="">Sprint</option>
            </select>
    </div>
        <div class="form-group">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <label for="selectUser">Arrival Notifications </label>
            <select id="selectUser" class="form-control selectWidth">
               <option class="">All Arrivals</option>
              <option class="">None</option>
              <option class="">Vendors Only</option>
            </select>
          </div>    

      </form>

    </div> <!-- End Row --> 
    </fieldset>
</div> <!-- End Container -->
```

Comment: Putting a fieldset within a form-group doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `<div class="container">` in your modal to which bootstrap gives a responsive width which can be wider than the modal, depending on viewing size.  If you remove either the `container` class or the `div` then your legend should act as expected.  Please note that this will cause your "phone details" forms to wrap.